# Grid View in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, google-cloud-firestore, gridview

I have created a Grid view Table in asp.net from Cloud Firestore. First I created a list to push the data in Class then I bind that class to Grid View. I have also implemented Pagging of 10 in the Gridview.

I have 33 rows in my table but when the grid view load after 33 row1 gets autopopulated.

Below is the code.

**Grid View Load : **

```
 private async void LoadGridView()
    {
    Query qref = fstrore.Collection("User").Document(UID).Collection("Product");
    QuerySnapshot snap = await qref.GetSnapshotAsync();
    foreach (DocumentSnapshot pn in snap)
    {
    ProDetails pro = pn.ConvertTo<ProDetails>();
    ProName.Add(new ProDetails()
    {
    ProductName = pro.ProductName,
    ProductQuantity = pro.ProductQuantity,
    PricePerPiece = pro.PricePerPiece,
    ProductPacket = pro.ProductPacket,
    ProductDistributor = pro.ProductDistributor,
    ProductCategory = pro.ProductCategory,
    ProductExpiryDt = pro.ProductExpiryDt,
    ProductAddDt = pro.ProductAddDt.Date,
    ProductUpdateDt = pro.ProductUpdateDt.Date,
    ProductUpdateFlag = pro.ProductUpdateFlag
    });
    }
    GD1.DataSource = ProName;
    GD1.DataBind();
    }
```

**Pagging :**

```
    {
    GD1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    this.LoadGridView();
    }
```

**ASPX Code :**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GD1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="GD1_PageIndexChanging"
    Style="margin-top: 20px; width: 100%; border-inline-width: 0.5px; border-block-width: 0.5px" PagerSettings-FirstPageText="First"
    PagerSettings-LastPageText="Last" PagerSettings-Position="TopAndBottom" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgstyle" PagerSettings-Mode="Numeric"
    HorizontalAlign="NotSet" PagerSettings-NextPageText="Next" PagerSettings-PreviousPageText="Prev" PagerSettings-Visible="True" PagerStyle-BackColor="#EAFAF1" PagerSettings-PageButtonCount="4" RowStyle-Wrap="True">
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SrNo">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <%--Name --%>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Name">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <%#Eval("ProductName") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <%--Quantity --%>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <%#Eval("ProductQuantity")%>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <%--Price --%>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price Per Piece">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <%#Eval("PricePerPiece") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <%--Packet --%>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Packet Quantity">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <%#Eval("ProductPacket") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <%--Disributor --%>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Distributor">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <%#Eval("ProductDistributor") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <%--Category --%>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Category">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <%#Eval("ProductCategory") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <%--Expiry --%>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Expiry Date">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <%#Eval("ProductExpiryDt", "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <%--Add Date --%>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Added On">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <%#Eval("ProductAddDt", "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <%--Update Date --%>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Update Date">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <%#Eval("ProductUpdateDt", "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <%--Update Flag --%>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Update Flag">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <%#Eval("ProductUpdateFlag") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#D4E6F1" CssClass="gdheader" />
    <RowStyle CssClass="gdrow" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

[Page 4 where you get row first automatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Godnk.png)
[Page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRaqr.png)

Please let me know where am i getting this wrong

Comment: And where is ProName defined, or created, or loaded? You need to provide that part.

Comment: So i have defined List<ProDetails> ProName = new List<ProDetails>();